# Terms clustering and visualisation using cosine in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, text-mining

I am newbie in text mining and R. I doing terms clustering using kmeans from a set of documents. In grouping the terms I used cosine formula. There are 57 terms of 839 document I want to cluster. But somehow, my supervisor said I the process is not correct because there's overlap in the plotting.

Here's TFIDF matrix
[image]

Here's the code I used

```
dokumen <- read.csv("dokumen.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header=TRUE)
corp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(dokumen))
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(tolower))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*", "", x)
removeURL2 <- function(x) gsub("www[[:alnum:][:punct:]]*", "", x)
removeEmail <- function(x) gsub ("[[:alnum:] [:punct:]] *?@ [:alnum:][:punct:]]*", "", x)
delPunct <- content_transformer(function(x) {return (gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", x))})
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(removeURL))
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(removeURL2))
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(removeEmail))
corp <- tm_map(corp, delPunct)
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, stopwords("smart"))
corp <- tm_map(corp, stemDocument, language = "english")
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeWords, c("australia", "australian", "indonesia", "indonesian", "embassi", "january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december", "past", "yesterday", "today", "present", "tomorrow", "day", "week", "month", "year", "time", "hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion", "countri", "world", "nation", "one", "two", "three", "four", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve"))
corp <- tm_map(corp, stripWhitespace)
tdm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
m <- as.matrix(tdm)
dtmi <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp, control = list(weighting = weightTfIdf))
m1 <- as.matrix(dtmi)
dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtmi, 0.79)
m2 <- as.matrix(dtms)
m3 <- 1 - crossprod_simple_triplet_matrix(dtms)/(sqrt(col_sums(dtms^2) %*% t(col_sums(dtms^2))))
km.res <- eclust(m3, "kmeans", k = 3, nstart = 100, graph = FALSE)
```

But when I visualised into 4 clusters there's overlap that my supervisor said that incorrect result. K means result shouldn't overlap. Here's the image
[image]

Does anyone can help whether I used the correct code. Or is there any action I should do with the dtm before clustering? Thank you very much!

Wishnu, Jakarta

Answer (score 0):

Kmeans should not overlap in 2 dimensions.

But your data has more dimensions, so they may overlap in the *projection*.

Comment: I see, Thanks for the enlightnment. Anyway, do you know or anyone knows simple code for 3D clusters projection in R? Because I got some examples, I need to determine X,Y,Z first and I have lack of understanding on that. Please help. Thanks much guys.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, perfectly separated clusters could be hard to achieve in text mining, depending on the characteristics of your corpus and the amount of words that compose the vocabulary you are working with.

However, it could be possible to improve your result by specifying a different number of clusters and checking if the clusters become more separated, as requested by your supervisor.

For estimating the optimal number of cluster there are some methods you can try to apply, such as the Elbow method, the Silhouette method and the Gap statistic. Since you are already using the FactoExtra package for the cluster analysis (eclust function in your code), you can compute all the three metrics using the fviz_nbclust function of the same package. You can find [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.5/topics/fviz_nbclust) a useful documentation about this function.